# How to find the objects connected by lines openCV python

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, computer-vision

Hi  please check the bellow image  [The image is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MwuoE.png)

What I actually want is
1)which line is connected which rectangle using OpenCV
For Ex- Suppose if the line connected to first and third triangle / rectangle then it will return a dictionary like `{"line_1" :[triangle_1 , rectabgle_2 ,traingale_3]  ,}`

Key as line and values as connected objects

I tried my best but I am facing issue from the rectangle findings and finding the perpendicular lines

Also if you have any logic please let me know

Answer (score 0):

I am not going to write any code here but just a simple approach that you can use to get desired result:

1. Binarize image such that lines/rectangles/triangles are foreground pixels.
2. Run findContours to find boxes/triangles.
3. Do convex hull on them to classify (rectangle/triangle). Get bounding box.
4. Remove classified contours to get lines. Those should be the only remaining contours now.
5. Find which lines have extreme points close to which of the classified rectangles/triangles.

Opencv functions you might need: adaptiveThresholding, findContours, convexHull, etc.

Comment: @Dharman Thanks for reply. I already followed all steps which you are given .but problem is i am not able to detect the proper lines which are not  staight. they are perpendicular lines as well as not able to extract the rectangles because in my image it is returning various shapes considering as a rectangle.. This problem looks very simple but its not

Comment: @Murli, please show us results with what you have got with the above mentioned approach. With findContours you don't have to worry about lines being horizontal or perpendicular.

Comment: See this  [https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hKjW_axkMbCA0UqGCG51icWGq-Wtbrm4/view?usp=sharing]

Comment: You need to use cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL directive with find contours.  Can you post the code you are using for this? Do not use cv2.RETR_LIST, that will give you all the contours and you will find filtering hard for your use case.

Comment: You can also use cv2.RETR_CCOMP and use hierarchy-1 contours and use hierarchy-2 for further filtering, in case it is required. The additional benefit of using CCOMP is that it can tell you if a contour is parent or child and if it's closed or open.